# Can the Avro format be used for KSQL when using Apache Kafka without Confluent Platform?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I see in the docs that KSQL supports the Avro format through the Confluent Schema registry. But what if Apache Kafka is being used (not Confluent Platform)?

Is there an option to use an Avro SpecificRecord schema without using the schema registry?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Avro format with KSQL, it is necessary to have Confluent Schema Registry up and running.

You can read more details here.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/server-config/avro-schema.html#using-avro-in-ksql

Comment: So for someone using Azure HDInsight Kafka which doesn't use Confluent Kafka (and thereby not Confluent Schema Registry either), using KSQL with Avro is not possible at all?

Comment: Yep, this is how it is as of now. P.S. I am also using HDInsight Kafka but for avro schema managment, using Confluent Schema registry. You can spin up Confluent Enterprise service in Azure to use that

Comment: Interesting. I noticed some features of Confluent Enterprise on Azure Marketplace have a 30 day trial. Is the Schema registry not a part of that 30 day trial? So you are just pointing your Confluent Enterprise pieces over to the Kafka cluster on HDInsight instead of using the set of brokers, zookeepers and workers? Doesn't this end up costing more money that it otherwise would?

Comment: And can you tell me what our Confluent Enterprise setup looks like in terms of number of brokers, zookeepers, etc? Since the Confluent Enterprise wouldn't be used to actually store topics it seems like it could be given less resources.

Comment: Yes, it's the same Confluent Enterprise service. Schema registry is covered by Community License so not a problem. But other services i.e. Control Center, Replicator etc can be used for 30 days in trial mode. Further you have to buy license.  Yes, it costs extra money for the VMs you use as nodes. Depending on the usages, you can decide cluster size.

Comment: You can read here : https://dataanalytics.report/Resources/Whitepapers/00f914e6-195b-440d-a103-19abfabec869_w1.pdf  It explains how it is deployed

Comment: Thanks. I just created the Confluent Enterprise in my environment. I'm curious whether I need all these servers just to do Schema Registry or if I can get away with much less.

Comment: You can start with just 3 nodes and continue using Schema registry

Comment: @emirhosseini "Confluent Kafka" does not exist. That **is** Apache Kafka. Schema Registry is a free open-source component, with no license or enterprise installation required. You can start a VM or a Docker container just for the registry